# trying to dynamic asp:FileUpload , refresh trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i need the users of my web system to do uploads ( up 4 ).

the upload itself its working , but i dont want all for box appering at start, so tried to hide the 2nd ,3rd and 4th upload boxes until the user need them .

here the aspx code part

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="frm tam">
    </div>
    <div class="lin">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /></div>
    <div class="lin">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" Visible="false" /></div>
    <div class="lin">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" Visible="false" /></div>
    <div class="lin">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" Visible="false" /></div>
    <div class="lin">
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD File" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnRem" runat="server" Text="Remove File" OnClick="btnRem_Click" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the code behind to show and hide the boxes

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload2.Visible == false)
    {
        FileUpload2.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (FileUpload3.Visible == false)
    {
        FileUpload3.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (FileUpload4.Visible == false)
    {
        FileUpload4.Visible = true;
    }
}

protected void btnRem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload4.Visible == true)
    {
        FileUpload4.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (FileUpload3.Visible == true)
    {
        FileUpload3.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (FileUpload2.Visible == true)
    {
        FileUpload2.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

and when i click on Add File, the new box appear but the filepaths selected on the other boxes are cleared. Can i avoid this clear ?

*edit: i´m using net framework 4.0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file get lost on postback. Alternatively, you can achieve that with JavaScript

```
<div id="div1">
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">   <!-- visibility:hidden -->
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none">
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none">
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Then put each FileUpload control in each of the divs.

```
<input type="button" valud="Add" onclick="addControls()" />
```

Then use JavaScript to make them visible

```
function addControls()
{
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'inline-block';
   //$('#div2').show(); <--- JQuery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that uploading files works slightly differently to most input controls...

Rather than posting the file path value that is entered, it actually posts the file content so 
on postback this value gets lost.

It seems to me like your best bet is to do something with javascript on the client to show/hide these upload controls. This would also be a better user experience as the user wouldn't have to wait for postback each time.

You could do this with jQuery...

http://jsfiddle.net/BAwfH/2/

```
<fieldset>
<div class="frm tam">
</div>
<div class="lin">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="lin">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="lin">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="lin">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" class="add-button" runat="server" Text="ADD File" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRem" runat="server" Text="Remove File" OnClick="btnRem_Click" />
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var lines = $('.lin');
lines.hide();
lines.filter(':first').show();

$('.add-button').click(function(){
    lines.filter(':hidden:first').show();

    if(lines.filter(':hidden').length == 0)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

});